# Redux-persist is returning initial State instead of persisting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I have added `redux-persist` in my code and it isn't persisting the state, instead I am always getting the initial state.

Here's the code of my `root-reducer`

```js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import userReducer from "./Users/user-reducer";
import cartReducer from "./Cart/cart-reducer";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  whitelist: ["cart"],
};
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  cart: cartReducer,
});
export default persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
```

and this is my `store.js` file

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import rootReducer from "./root-reducer";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";

const middlewares = [logger];
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Here's my `index.js` file

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store, persistor } from "./redux/Store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
          <App />
        </PersistGate>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Whenever I am refreshing my page with the initial state, I am getting `rehydrated: true` but after firing some action I am getting `rehydrated: false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your reducer.js and make sure the bottom of the reducer in the file is

```
default:
      return state;
```

and not

````
default:
      return {
        ...state,
      };```
````

Comment: could you tell me the reason why need do this