# With Redux-Persist, how do I set the initial state of my reducer to be what is stored in local storage?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, local-storage, redux-persist

I'm using Ionic 7, React 18, and Redux-Toolkit and Redux-Persist. I would like to persist one of my states (cart) to local storage. I have set up my cartSlice as below

```js
interface CartState {
  [key: string]: OrderItem[];
}

const initialState: CartState = {};

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    ...
    },

    clearCart: (state) => {
      ...
    },
  },
});

export const {
  addToCart,
  clearCart,
} = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

and set up my root persist reducer as below

```js
const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  blacklist: ['auth'],
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
};

const authPersistConfig = {
  key: 'auth',
  storage: sessionStorage,
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: persistReducer(authPersistConfig, authReducer),
  cart: cartReducer,
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(rootPersistConfig, rootReducer);

export default persistedReducer;
```

in which I load this into my store like below

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer, // rootReducer,
  devTools: import.meta.env.VITE_NODE_ENV !== "production",
});
```

What I'm not clear about is how to set my initial state to be local storage, assuming there is already something there. Every time I load my app, my initial state is reset to "{}", due to how I set it in my slice, but I can't figure out how to tell my state that the initial state can be loaded from local storage, if the state is already there.

Comment: dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67244076/redux-persist-is-returning-initial-state-instead-of-persisting

Comment: The question you linked to concerns Redux never persisting state.  My setup persists state just fine, it just doesn't load the initial state from local storage (if I hard-code an initial state, that gets loaded and persisted just fine)

Comment: Dave, think you could stand up a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of this code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: FWIW I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describe here in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/with-redux-persist-how-do-i-set-the-initial-state-of-my-reducer-to-be-what-is-s-9ldmsm) demo. Feel free to fork it and add more of your actual code to see if something else creates the issue. If so, please share it back so that we can inspect it.

Comment: @DrewReese, you cracked the case.  Thanks to your example, I realize I am not wrapping my "store" in a persistStore ("persistor = persistStore(store);") and further, I was still using PErsistGate.  Going to give these a try and report back.

Comment: Yeah that was the issue.  If you want to add an answer and include the sandbox link you provided, you got yourself a bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you are following all of the setup/configuration steps.

```
const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: storage,
  blacklist: ["auth"],
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2
};

const authPersistConfig = {
  key: "auth",
  storage: sessionStorage
};

const persistedAuthReducer = persistReducer(authPersistConfig, authReducer);

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: persistedAuthReducer,
  cart: cartReducer
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(rootPersistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer // rootReducer,
  devTools: import.meta.env.VITE_NODE_ENV !== "production",
});

const persistor = persistStore(store); // <-- persist store

...

<Provider store={store}>
  <PersistGate persistor={persistor}> // <-- persist gate
    ....
  </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

[image: Edit with-redux-persist-how-do-i-set-the-initial-state-of-my-reducer-to-be-what-is-s]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `stateReconciler` option in the `rootPersistConfig` configuration object to ensure that the initial state of your cart is populated from local storage if it is available. The `stateReconciler` function is in charge of combining the persisted state from local storage with the reducer's default initial state.

The following is an example of how to use the `stateReconciler` function:

```js
const stateReconciler = (storeState, persistedState) => {
  // Check if there's cart data in local storage
  if (persistedState.cart) {
    // Merge the persisted cart data with the default initial state
    return {
      ...storeState,
      cart: persistedState.cart,
    };
  }

  // If no cart data exists in local storage, use the default initial state
  return storeState;
};
```

Also include the following function in your `rootPersistConfig` configuration:

```
const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  blacklist: ['auth'],
  stateReconciler: stateReconciler,
};
```

The initial state of your cart will be populated from local storage if available with this setup, ensuring that the cart remains persistent between page reloads or app restarts.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't working for me when I do a hard page reload (i.e. type in the URL into the address bar).  Specifically, I'm not observing the reconciler is ever called.  I added a "console.log" line right before "if (persistedState.cart) {".